# Is this correct Soap Format for check_in service in oracle UCM?

Tags: xml, oracle, soap

When i am using this Soap service in iOS application to add an document to oracle UCM

These parameters for CHECKIN_UNIVERSAL are defined:

doFileCopy, dDocName, dDocTitle, dDocType, dSecurityGroup, dDocAuthor, dDocAccount

primaryFile

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
"<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" 
xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" 
xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
"<SOAP-ENV:Body>"
"<idc:service xmlns:idc=\"http://http://192.168.1.29:16200/cs/idcplg/"  
"IdcService=\"CHECKIN_UNIVERSAL\">\n"
"<idc:document dID=\"\">\n"
"<idc:field name=\"Auth\">Internet</idc:field>\n"
"<idc:field name=\"dID\"></idc:field>\n"
"<idc:field name=\"dDocAuthor\">sysadmin</idc:field>\n"
"<idc:field name=\"dDocTitle\">USER_TITLE</idc:field>\n"
"<idc:field name=\"dDocType\">RR</idc:field>\n"
"<idc:field name=\"doFileCopy\">0</idc:field>\n"
"<idc:field name=\"dSecurityGroup\">PUBLIC</idc:field>\n"
"<idc:field 
 name=\"primaryFile\">/Users/DesktopMacMini/Documents/test.html</idc:field>\n"
 "<idc:field name=\"dDocAccount\">Ext</idc:field>\n"
 "</idc:document>\n"
 "</idc:service>\n"
 "</SOAP-ENV:Body>\n"
 "</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>\n"

This error i am getting.. this service i am using in iOS application

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<SOAP-ENV:Fault>
<faultcode>Client</faultcode>
<faultstring>A formatting error was encountered while parsing (null). The tag(s) 
'soap:Envelope,SOAP-ENV:Body' were not properly closed.</faultstring>
</SOAP-ENV:Fault>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

give any solutions for this...

Comment: Can we write the id_services of Oracle Content Server system through the URL
eg:http://cs.example.com/cs/idcplgIdcService=GET_SEARCH_RESULTS&QueryText=oracle&ftx=1&AdvSearch=True&ResultCount=25&SortField=dInDate&SortOrder=Desc

Answer (score 0):

Yes SOAP request you wrote is correct but String formatting is wrong here...wrong formatting is done here:
"http://192.168.1.29:16200/cs/**idcplg/"**  it has to be "http://192.168.1.29:16200/cs/**idcplg/\""**